# dynamic resource for object in Terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-modules

I want to call terraform module in the next way:

```
module "database_role" {
source = "modules/roles"

project_id = "testid"
role_name = "testrole"

  actions = {
    action: ["ENABLE_PROFILER", "DROP_DATABASE"]
    database_name: ["test_db", test_db_2"]
  }
```

roles module definition i created is:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_custom_db_role" "custom_role" {
  project_id = "xxx-xxx"
  role_name  = "yyy-yyy"

  dynamic "actions" {
    for_each = flatten([
      for item in range(length(local.actions["action"])): {
        act = local.actions["action"][item]
        db_name = local.actions.database_name
      }
     ])
     content {
       action = actions.value.act
       resources {
         cluster = "false"
         database_name = actions.value.db_name
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

as result i want to see 4 actions properly generated(each database has roles 2 defined):

```
  actions {
    action = "ENABLE_PROFILER"
    resources {
      cluster         = "false"
      database_name   = "test_db"
    }
  }


  actions {
    action = "DROP_DATABASE"
    resources {
      cluster         = "false"
      database_name   = "test_db"
    }
  }

  actions {
    action = "ENABLE_PROFILER"
    resources {
      cluster         = "false"
      database_name   = "test_db_2"
    }
  }


  actions {
    action = "DROP_DATABASE"
    resources {
      cluster         = "false"
      database_name   = "test_db_2"
    }
  }
```

I'm getting error: The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. What i'm doing wrong in module dynamic resource? Thanks

Comment: "The given key does" -  which key? Where does it exactly occur?

Comment: Your looping seems to be incorrect. You have to iterate through the product of `action` and `database_name` by looking at your exptected response. However, you are just iterating through `action` list. I guess you are hitting array outbound kind of errors because of this incorrect looping. Can you reframe your question? I really don't know where the roles are defined?

Comment: Could you please help to create correct loop? Role defined using mongodbatlas_custom_db_role resource and i need to create a set of actions for each database. Thanks

Comment: @BigBoss , did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @ManishIarhovich, no